# Is this question opinion based?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, opinion-based

[Is this comment acceptable under *your* C coding standards?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/340879/is-this-comment-acceptable-under-your-c-coding-standards)

As my comment states

> I am not asking if they think it acceptable, but, rather if their
>   organization permits it. Which, while arguably opinion-based at second
>   remove, is factual within the context of this site and this question.
>   You may consider this analogous to asking if it is
>   legal to drink beer at age 18 where you live. You may have a personal
>   opinion, but I asking about the law.

**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I'd close it as too broad. But I think that primarily opinion based works just as well. You're conducting a poll. We expect that questions [meet our guidelines](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and many of those guidelines preclude poll questions. In a poll, all answers are equally valid and there is no actual problem to be solved.

Comment: Thank you for the clarificatoin.